# Weird PHP issue - DatePeriod does not show February while iterating through months.

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$from = '2014-10-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2015-05-31 23:30:00';

$start = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($from), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));
$end = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($to), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$count = 0;

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-M').'<br>';
}

exit;
```

I need to get the month's starting date and month's ending date for a certain period. So, I use the DatePeriod.

But, this only shows this output.

```
2014-Sep
2014-Oct
2014-Nov
2014-Dec
2015-Jan
2015-Mar
2015-Apr
2015-May
```

And somehow the month February is missed.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: seems to work fine [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Sh24DK)

Comment: Why the complexity of `new DateTime('@' . strtotime($from), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));` when you can just do `new DateTime($from, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));`? You don't need to use strtotime() at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `strtotime` and `@` from the code and it'll work fine. As there is no need to make a timestamp of your `date` value

```
$from = '2014-10-01 00:00:00';
$to = '2015-05-31 23:30:00';

$start = new DateTime($from, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));
$end = new DateTime($to, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$count = 0;

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-M').'<br>';
}
```